# How to Make Program Keep Starting at Startup When User Disabled in Task Manager

Tags: windows, inno-setup, desktop-application, startup

I've to make a clone some desktop security software. This software just only have to run on Windows 10. The software has features that force keep starting at startup, even though user disabled in Task Manager. This features is needed because user must login first to the software before starting to use it.

What I've done to make software run at startup only use this script with Inno Setup 5 installer

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "My Application Name"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

How can I make my program keep running at startup?

Comment: Perhaps there is a language barrier, but the question is not clear. Managing startup of applications is a Windows question (Inno Setup merely lets you add the files and registry entries to implement it). I think you are better off asking your question on superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will ask in superuser.com